# How to show two charts in the same html page

Tags: javascript, canvas, smoothie.js

I'm working on a project where I should show two kind of charts :

- a Real time Chart and I'm using smoothie.js lib for this.
- a normal chart with zoom option and I'm using canvas lib for this.

as it showen in the code below the smoothie.js use on the body tag an "onload"  :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <html>
        <head>
              <title>Pression en temps réel</title>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

               <script type="text/javascript" src="smoothie.js"></script>
               <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

               <script type="text/javascript">

               window.bufferX = [];

               setInterval(function () {

            if( typeof lastid == 'undefined' ) {
                $.get( "../be.php/lastid_1", function( dataA ) {
                 lastid = dataA[0].id_x+1;  
                })
            }
            else {
                $.get( "../be.php/1&"+lastid, function( dataB ) {
                     var i =0;
                     var j=0;

                     if( typeof counter == 'undefined' ) {
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    if( typeof pck_prev == 'undefined' ) {
                                pck_prev = -1;
                            }

                    lastid = dataB[0].last_id;

                     for(i=0;i<dataB.length;i++) {

                        for(j=0;j<dataB[i].data.length;j++) {
                            if(dataB[i].data[j] !== "" && dataB[i].data[j] !== 0 && typeof  dataB[i].data[j] !== 'undefined' && pck_prev !== dataB[i].pck) {
                                window.bufferX.push(dataB[i].data[j]);
                            }
                        }
                        pck_prev = dataB[i].pck;
                     }
                     if(typeof window.bufferX[counter] == 'undefined') {
                       data_p.append(new Date().getTime(), window.bufferX[counter-1]);
                     }
                })
            } 
        },3000);



          var data_p = new TimeSeries();
          setInterval(function() {

           if(window.bufferX.length>50 && counter <window.bufferX.length)
                                 {

                                     if( typeof counter == 'undefined' ) {
                                        counter = 0;
                                    }

                                    else {
                                            data_p.append(new Date().getTime(), window.bufferX[counter]);
                                            counter++;
                                    } 
                                   }
          }, 250);       

  function createTimeline() {
    var chart = new SmoothieChart({responsive: true});
    chart.addTimeSeries(data_p, { strokeStyle: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)', fillStyle: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)', lineWidth: 4 });
    chart.streamTo(document.getElementById("chart"), 250);
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function () {

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {
          zoomEnabled: true, 
          title:{
            text: "Try Zooming And Panning" 
          },
          axisY:{
            includeZero: false
          },
          data: data,  // random generator below

       });

        chart.render();
      }

        var limit = 1000;    //increase number of dataPoints by increasing this
        var y = 0;
        var data = []; var dataSeries = { type: "line" };
        var dataPoints = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
            y += (Math.random() * 10 - 5);
             dataPoints.push({
              x: i - limit / 2,
              y: y                
               });
            }
         dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
         data.push(dataSeries);               

       </script>
       </head>
  <body onload="createTimeline()">

           <canvas id="chart" style="width:100%; height:700px;"></canvas>
           <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 700px; width: 100%;"> 
                   </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

The problem is if I delete onload from body tag I will get the canvas chart only and if I let it I will get the real time chart only.

I would like to have both charts showen on my page.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.onload` and `<body onload="yourfunction();">` are different ways of using the same event and you are using both which is causing the issue. The easiest way to fix this problem is that you should write both the implementation in one event either in `window.onload` or in `onload` of body tag.
Find the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/La8gfnub/1/).

You can find both the chart are visible at the same time.